# composer-playground is throwing error

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I followed the steps given in the link:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html
when i executed the command "composer-playground" i am getting the below error

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: listen EADDRINUSE   :::8080

Please note i have closed all the browsers before running this command.

Thanks,
Smitha

Answer (score 1):

You have another server on your machine listening in port 8080. You can start playground on a different port using the -p or --port option. For example `composer-playground -p 8090` will start composer playground listening on port 8090. You then will need to specify that port on the url in your browser, for example `http://localhost:8090`